# ng-disabled angular js to evaluate a function that gets $http.get

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

am trying to make my ng-disbaled button to evaluate to a function in the controller that returns a request from $http.get here are my codes

my html code

```
<a class="btn btn-warning"  ng-click="upVote(item,me.email);" ng-disabled="votecheck(item,me.email) != 'canvote'">
```

controller

```
$scope.votecheck = function(item,emailid){
    var email = emailid;

http.post('ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email).success(function(data)
{

        if(data === "CanVote")
        {
            return "canvote";
        }
else
{
    return "cant vote";
}
    });

};
```

my php echo's can vote or cant vote if over an sql state to the database
somebody please help make this work

note my item id is already preloaded with a previous scope function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hi all i was able to solve my problem using traditionall javascript .ajax with this

Thanx y'all    

$scope.votecheck = function(item,emailid){
        var email = emailid;
       var jsonData = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
              url: 'ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
                }).responseText;
    if(jsonData === "CanVote"){

        return true;
    }
    else{

        return false;
    }   //return "canvote";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$scope.votecheck = function (item, emailid) {

     return $http.post('upload.php').then(function(data) {

         if (data === "CanVote")
             {
                  $scope.returnValue = "canvote";
             }

             else
             {
                  $scope.returnValue = "cant vote";
              }

                  return $scope.returnValue;
              });

};

$scope.votecheck(item, emailid).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: your edited answer returns an object instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

Since you're making an asynchronous call with http.post, you can't "return" a value per se.

You'll need to set some `canVote` property on your scope based on the data coming into your success callback.

So the html would be like:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning"  ng-click="upVote(item,me.email);" ng-disabled="!canVote">
```

Your new function would be like:

```
function voteCheck(item,emailid) {
  var email = emailid;
  http.post('ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email).success(function(data) {
    $scope.canVote = (data === 'CanVote');
  });
}

voteCheck(item, emailid);
```

Comment: thanx jfairbank but when i tried your code it returns ReferenceError: item is not defined, and wen i remove that function it disable alld ng-click

Comment: Sorry, I just made an assumption about your variable names. Basically, you'll need to call that function with the arguments you used to call the $scope.voteCheck method with.

Comment: its the same variable name i used it in an ng-repeat so the item get passed in and takes the item.id and email passed in

Comment: That's right. Getting late for me heh. Your best bet would probably be to have a payload from your server for all items you'll iterate over in ngRepeat. So you would load the data in your main controller, which would include if each item can vote. That way you'll also reduce the number of API calls you're making. Will that work? Do you have a jsfiddle or something I could look at later?

Comment: i dunno if it will work yet but am goin to try and figure out a way for it to work.. am retrieving values over database so having it return wild b loads of work.. and i dont tink i can put the whole project on jsfiddle

Comment: Hi thanx for your input i was able to solve my problem using the traditional jquery .ajax .responsetext here   $scope.votecheck = function(item,emailid){
 var email = emailid;
   var jsonData = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
          url: 'ajax/voters.php?id='+item.ID+'&email='+email,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false
            }).responseText;
if(jsonData === "CanVote"){

 return true;
}
else{

 return false;
} //return "canvote";
}